# Looping Through An Array and Dividing Each Value By 100

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hey this is my first question and I'm just finding my way with JS. I have an array which is set, I want to loop through it and divide each value by 100, then print the output to the console. Here's where I'm up to

```
var example =[5, 10, 15, 20]

for (var i=0; i < example.length; i++) {
  (example[i/100]);
}

console.log(example);
```

I know my problem is with the `(example[i/100]);` line but I'm not sure how to fix, any help appreciated :-)

so my goal is to get to

0.5, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2

Comment: Change `(example[i/100]);` to `example[i] /= 100`

Comment: Also, if you divide 5 by 100, you will get 0.05

Comment: It's unclear if you want to store the results in-place in the array, or just print it while leaving the array untouched.

Comment: He says that he wants to print it only. "then print the output to the console". @Tushar

Comment: Thanks @Tushar super helpful

Comment: @AleOtero93 I don't see the "only" in his post. I'm hoping OP will edit it to clarify the question.

Comment: It seems quite clear that he wants to update the array, then print the updated array. Assuming that is the case, several of the answers, including the accepted one, don't do exactly that.

Comment: yes i do want to update the array, does this change the code slightly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*UPDATED to save the modified values in-place*

There's not much reason to log() each value separately. You could streamline the code with something like this, with pretty ES6 arrow functions and ES5 array methods:

```
var example = [5, 10, 15, 20]

console.log(example = example.map(x => x/100))
```

Note: arrow functions such as `x => x/100` currently work in a very small subset of Web browsers. If you want to publish a web app or page right now, you should use a standard anonymous function: `function (x) { return x/100 }`.

Comment: I'm not knocking Touffy's answer here, OP, but considering that you appear to be new with JS, ES6 might be a little out of your skill range if you don't understand simple ES5 array manipulation. You can't use that code currently without transpiling it.

Comment: Why the `{}` around the fat arrow function body? Also, can you show him how to actually change the array values, since that may be what he intended?

Comment: @Andy Good point, but actually, the code works fine in Chrome.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the heads-up @torazaburo.

Comment: @Andy I could point out that using `for..in` on arrays is not recommended, especially for beginners. Agreed, arrow functions only work in V8 right now. ES5 array methods are more widely supported.

Comment: @torazaburo It's not strictly necessary but I use them to indicate that I don't really want to return anything. And I asked if he wanted to change the values, I'll edit my post now that he's clarified that.

Comment: @Touffy, not using `for in` loops is standard practice for a number of reasons and it would be good to remind anyone, not just a beginner, if they used it of the implications. As I said, I wasn't knocking your answer, just suggesting that for someone who doesn't understand the current standard JS, while _useful_, ES6 might be a step further than a beginner can handle.

Comment: Depends on background. Arrow functions aren't quirky in the way that some older JavaScript features are, and they look like familiar maths. Just because we are used to some things from the 1990s, doesn't mean it's easier for a beginner to start with them rather than the shiny new toys that were added to the standard after a lot more thinking and discussion ;)

Answer (score 4):

> divide each value by 100,

Yes, you want to divide each value by 100, but also store the result **back** into the array. In JavaScript, if you want to do some calculation and store the results, you need to say

```
left-hand-side = calculation
```

In other words, you need to use the **assignment** operator (`=`) to assign the results of the calculation to some variable, array element, or property.

In your case, the "calculation" is the value of the array element divided by 100, so it would be

```
example[i] / 100
```

You may wonder why `example[i/100]` does not work. Think about it. The thing that comes inside the `[]` is an **index into the array**. You don't want to divide the *index `i`* by 100; you want to divide the *value at index `i`* by 100.

The result of this calculation--dividing the element at index `i` by 100--you want to put **back** into the array at the same location. So the "left-hand-side" is also `element[i]`. The entire statement thus is

```
example[i] = example[i] / 100;
```

Your attempt, which was

```
( example [ i/ 100] )
```

is therefore missing the mark on a couple of levels. First of all, you are dividing the index by 100, instead of dividing the value at the index by 100. Second, you are not assigning the result to anything--so the result will just be thrown away.

Merely changing the line you knew was shaky, to the above `example[i] = example[i] / 100;` will make your code work perfectly. You don't need `forEach`, or `map`, or arrow functions (although I hope you will learn what they are and start using them sometime soon).

In this particular case, we are assigning the result of dividing a particular array element by 100 back to that **same** array element. In such cases, JavaScript provides special assignment operators, which allow you to avoid duplicating the reference to the array element (or variable, or object property). In this case, you're interested in the "division assignment operator", which you can use as

```
example[i] /= 100;
           ^^
```

But there's no particular need to use that, other than brevity.

Answer (score 3):

change the `example[i/100]` to `example[i] /100` and you can `console.log` each response from inside the for loop.

```
var example = [5, 10, 15, 20];

for (var i = 0; i < example.length; i++) {
  console.log(example[i] / 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler massive help :-)

Comment: Glad to help.  If your not using jsbin.com, you can play around with JS there.  Here is your example: https://jsbin.com/joqaxihuyu/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: Another alternative, I always use forEach in place of for:
example.forEach(function(i) { console.log( i / 100) })

Comment: thanks a lot, can't explain how much it was annoying me :-)

Comment: Or use `for..of` which behaves more consistently with arrays and would shorten your code

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your code (see below):

```
var example = [5, 10, 15, 20];

example.forEach(function(i) {
  console.log(example[i] / 100);
});
```

So a couple of comments on the above:

1. I believe you meant to get as a result: 0.05, 0.1., 0.15, and 0.2 by dividing by 100.. so keep in mind your math.
2. You are dividing by the index of the array `example`, change your syntax to represent the following: `example[i] = example[i] / 10;`, which translates to short hand form: `example[i] /= 100;`.
3. Look into the `forEach` function, which works as a for loop over an array and it can be an excellent implementation on your example.
4. Assuming you want to extend your knowledge, it would be great if you jumped into a beginner course. I can't think of anywhere better to start than here: [CodeAcademy, Javascript courses](https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript)... I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The non-ES6 code might read like this. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) returns a *new* array where each element has been changed by the function. It's up to you whether you want a new array, or whether you use a `for` loop to change the elements of the existing array.

```
var example = [5, 10, 15, 20];
```

**Example 1**

```
var out = example.map(function (el) {
    return el / 100;
});

console.log(out); // [ 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2 ]
```

**Example 2**

```
for (var i = 0, l = example.length; i < l; i++) {
    example[i] = example[i] / 100;
}

console.log(example);
```